Weird normals when baking, could’nt fix for 2 days
I’ve been trying to bake normals from a high poly karambit to a low poly one using a cage. but no matter what I try, there is always some issue on the baked normals, Ive been trying to fix this for 2 days and theres been some progress but please help. here there is weird glitch on the ring part of the karambit and the cyan color on the part where the handle and the blade meets

this is the best i did to reduce that part, I made the cage by duplicating the low poly and making it slightly bigger than both low poly and high poly, I also tried just using extrusion field when baking but thats worse.
also, it seems very low detail in some parts and much more details in other parts of the normal map, for example the finger parts you can barely see and the ring part is very sharp, or is that normal?
i have no idea why this glitch is happening, I scoured the internet for a solution but none of them worked, I tried changing all the settings when baking but no result, actually worse results
and also when I zoom out there is some z fighting even tho the cage fully overlaps both the high poly and low poly
here is the .blend file, please check it out:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RpyrY0P28vRT2rfzdtLf9Of-OO03r5ZT/view?usp=drive_link

Long distance Z fighting is usual. Did you check your mesh for duplicates and disconnections? (edit, a, m, by distance). When you make a cage, make sure you don't add or remove any vertex, it must have the same amount as the original. Also make sure your cage doesn't cross over itself (this sometimes happens in bevels on concave parts)

yes when i made th cage using alt s, there were some parts overlapping each other but i fixed all of them, and the vertices count are the same with low poly one

It seems to work fine, you don't need the Cage option, bring back the Ray Distance to 0, bake?

is there no weird glith on the ring part when you bake it? Setting the ray distance to 0 didn't help, same thing

As moonboots has already mentioned there wasn't a lot wrong with the normal bake using the default bake settings and the cage wasn't necessary for the bake.
Some of the vertices of the low poly ring needed editing to better align with the shape of the high poly ring.

Also I edited the UV seams of the ring so that the two halves would unwrap as mirrored copies of each other.
There was a lot of wasted space in the UV space so I created a new UV map then re-unwrapped the low poly model and arranged the islands a little better.

When baking I found in necessary to set an Extrusion value of 0.01

With the normal map connected the only artifacts I found was on the edge of the Blade and I was unable to fix these. A workaround for these could be to manually move the effected UV edges of the blade in a little after baking.

The modified version can be downloaded from here :


thank you so much, this helped. Just one question, when should I use usually use cages for normal baking?

Cage is when you can't count on the low-poly topology to bake correctly because the ray will easily meet reversed normals, for example at the crotch of a character, if you use a cage you don't have to move the faces of the low-poly to make the bake work correctly, instead move the faces of the cage
